# sending struct via Qt UDP

Tags: c++, qt, struct

I am trying to setup two way communication via the `QUdpSocket`. I am trying to send a struct consisting of a C++ Eigenvector and a double. I have tried serializing into a `QByteArray` as follows:

```
MyStruct toSend;
QByteArray buf;
QDataStream s(&buf, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
if (false) s.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
std::string vec_str = eigenToStr(toSend.vec);
s << (double)toSend.test1 << QString(vec_str.c_str());
```

Where `eigenToStr()` converts the Eigenvector to a string.

However, I am unable to read the message on the other end. When I convert back to a string before sending the `QByteArray`, I get `@ffffff`. So I assume it's an issue with the `QByteArray`/`QDataStream` conversion.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how I might serialize my struct so that I can send it via UDP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

QByteArray and QDataStream  cooperate very well:). If you really want write the raw data to  QDataStream , please use the  method :

```
int QDataStream::writeRawData(const char * s, int len)
```

And personally I prefer to overload << way to write user data to QDataStream, such as

```
QDataStream& operator <<(QDataStream& out,MyStruct & data)
```

Then probably code looks as :

```
   MyStruct toSend;
   QByteArray buf;
   QDataStream s(&buf, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   if (false) s.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);//false ?  
   s << toSend;
```